# jQuery & JavaScript Excercise: Adding Values On Condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

How do you make it calculate using JavaScript/jQuery based on condition:

- on radio button 'change' event.
- if user clicks "Yes" or "N/A", the value of text boxes with default values next to it will be added and reflected in Total

**HTML:**

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="radio" name="remark[]" value="Yes" class="answer">Yes
        <input type="radio" name="remark[]" value="No" class="answer">No
        <input type="radio" name="remark[]" class="answer">N/A
        <input type="text" name="point1" class="score" value="3">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="radio" name="remark[]" value="Yes" class="answer">Yes
        <input type="radio" name="remark[]" value="No" class="answer">No
        <input type="radio" name="remark[]" class="answer">N/A
        <input type="text" name="point2" class="score" value="2">
    </fieldset>
    Total<input type="text" name="total" class="result">
</form>
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `radio` instead of `checkbox`?

Comment: thanks i didn't notice that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Vanilla Javascript

Note: these scripts associate with forms that have the class name `calc`

This script will associate with the form, so if you have multiple instances each form will calculate separately.

Basically for each form select all input's with a value of 'Yes' which are checked, then find the score for that field set and add it to the total

([Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/34bst8xk/2/))

```
(function(){
    "use strict";
    function calculate() {
        var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.calc'), form, i;
        for (i = 0; form = forms[i]; i++) {
            var total = 0;
            var inputs = form.querySelectorAll('input[value="Yes"]:checked'), input, x;
            for (x = 0; input = inputs[x]; x++) {
                total += parseFloat(input.parentElement.lastElementChild.value);
            }
            form.lastElementChild.value = total;
        }
    }
    calculate();
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.calc input'), input, x;
    for(x = 0; input = inputs[x]; x++) {
        input.onchange = calculate;
    }
})();
```

#### jQuery

If you would like to use jQuery, this is the same script converted to jQuery

([Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/34bst8xk/1/))

```
(function(){
    "use strict";
    function calculate() {
        $('.calc').each(function(){
            var total = 0;
            $('input[value="Yes"]:checked', this).each(function(){
                total += parseFloat($('input.score', this.parentElement).val());
            });
            $('input.result', this).val(total);
        });
    }
    calculate();
    $('.calc input').on('change', calculate);
})();
```

Comment: Wow! Such clean short codes. Thank you for your big help!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand correctly, but first you'll need a few changes in your markup, `radio` groups should have different name so it'll be like `remark[0]` for first group and `remark[1]` for the second and so on. The "N/A" radios don't seem to have a value so I've added `value="NA"` to them. So your HTML will look like:

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="radio" name="remark[0]" value="Yes" class="answer" />Yes
        <input type="radio" name="remark[0]" value="No" class="answer" />No
        <input type="radio" name="remark[0]" value="NA" class="answer" />N/A
        <input type="text" name="point1" class="score" value="3" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="radio" name="remark[1]" value="Yes" class="answer" />Yes
        <input type="radio" name="remark[1]" value="No" class="answer" />No
        <input type="radio" name="remark[1]" value="NA" class="answer" />N/A
        <input type="text" name="point2" class="score" value="2" />
    </fieldset>Total
    <input type="text" name="total" class="result" />
</form>
```

Then we just listen to radio's `onchange` and if Yes or N/A is selected for each group, we have it's value to the total. I used `parseInt` on values since they're string and it seemed the values were supposed to work as numbers. (2+3 should be 5 and not 23).

```
$('form input[type=radio]').on('change', function() {
    var total = 0;
    $('form fieldset').each(function(i) {
        var point = parseInt($(this).find('input[type=text]').val());
        var val = $(this).children('[name="remark[' + i + ']"]:checked').val();
        if(val == "Yes" || val == "NA")
            total += point;
    });
    $('input[name="total"]').val(total);
});
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/zLLLj3tk/)